# how do i call a click event from a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, events, click

Here is my problem.

```
    string btn = "btn7";
    //this is the problem.
    btnClone.click += this.controles[btn]_click ;
```

so i like to use a string to share the event to the other button and the string is a must.

i hope that somebody can help me.

Comment: btn is a string type and not a control which inherits from the Control object. string types do not have a click event. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You want the string to share the control name?

Comment: well i have like 100 buttons and i like to use a contextmenustrip when you rightclick, you get the option "add to favorites" but each button needs to have that option. if you click on "add to favorites" you get a copy of that button in an other panel.

Comment: yes this.controles[string]_click like that but it doesnt work so i need an other option.

Comment: Why don't you try to put in words what you want because this code makes no sense.

Comment: @user2667389 - Don't be sarcastic.  You are the one coming here for help.  We are helping you not the other way around.  You question does not make any sense nor does your design.  This is his point.

Comment: @user2667389 I am a pretty tolerant guy but the quality of your question is really low. I rarely downvote (none of these downvotes is mine); and I intend to help even though the asker is not explaining his point properly. But this is a network for developers with certain quality-standards which you are not respecting at all. You haven't done any effort to make yourself clear and your question is, objectively speaking, horrible (and does not fit here). My intention was helping you to realise that it is impossible to get help here with this attitude.

Answer (score 2):

A more standard way to find a control by id would be

```
Button b = (Button)FindControl(btn);
```

You could also search like this if you don't know the id

```
   Button oldButt = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().(b => b.Name == btn).First();
```